# Draw a line chart using multiple columns data (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, multiple-columns

I am trying to draw a line chart from the following data. On the x-axis, I want to show the year, on the y-axis, I want to show the population of different 'Borough'. Basically, I want to draw the population of all the boroughs throughout the years. I wrote the following code to transpose the data and draw the line graph. I am getting error- "no numeric data to plot". First figure is of the transposed data, second figure is of the original data

```
bar_plot = bar_plot.transpose()
bar_plot
bar_plot.columns = ['NYC Total Population', 'Bronx Population', 'Brooklyn Population'   , 'Manhattan Population',   'Queens Population',    'Staten Island Population']
bar_plot.drop('Borough')
bar_plot.plot(kind = 'line', y = ['NYC Total Population',   'Bronx Population', 'Brooklyn Population'   , 'Manhattan Population',   'Queens Population',    'Staten Island Population'])
```

[image: I transposed the data and changed it to this]

[image: The original dataframe looked like this]

Comment: Have a look at the seaborn library which allows you to make plots easily with pandas. see: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

Comment: Could it be that your population data are in fact type category? Could you check what gives `bar_plot.dtypes` ?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I just checked, my datatype of all columns was an object, I changed it to int and it's working fine now

Comment: @ShivamGupta: no problem, glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no errors in your plot code.
This error occurs if data type is category. Take care to convert and verify for numeric type using for ex.:

```
bar_plot = bar_plot.apply(pd.to_numeric)
bar_plot.dtypes
```

The following simplified code gives a lineplot:

```
import pandas as pd

bar_plot = pd.DataFrame({'NYC Total Population': [200, 400, 600], 'Staten Island': [30, 60, 90]}, index=[1950, 1960, 1970])

bar_plot.plot(kind = 'line', y = ['NYC Total Population', 'Staten Island'])
```